# Duplicated id error, key is actually NOT duplicated

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, unique-constraint

I have the following query:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT
        profileid as id_user,
        cast(terms_accepted as boolean) as terms_accepted_passport,
        lastname as last_name_user,
        firstname as first_name_user,
        picture_serving_url as picture_user,
        is_active as status_user,
        is_passport_active as status_passport,
        language as language_id_user,
        to_timestamp(created, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as created_user,
        to_timestamp(modified, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as modified_user,
        passport_completion_level as completion_level_passport,
        email as email_user,
        about_me as description_user,
        uni_code as institution_id_user,
        to_json(metadata) as metadata_misc
    FROM import_temp_table
)
INSERT INTO passport (
    id,
    public,
    status,
    completion_level,
    user_id,
    terms_accepted
)
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM passport),
    TRUE,
    CASE status_passport
        WHEN LOWER('true') THEN 1
        WHEN LOWER('false') THEN 2
    END AS status_passport,
    completion_level_passport,
    id_user,
    terms_accepted_passport
FROM data
```

So I was trying this query and it throws the following error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "passport_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(108) already exists.
```

Problem is, `id 108` DOESN'T exist. When you perform a single insert with the hardcoded id as 108, it performs it, however, when you try and loop it like this here, it doesn't. Any idea how can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Table definition for Passport is here:

```
CREATE TABLE public.passport
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('passport_id_seq'::regclass),
    public boolean,
    status integer,
    completion_level character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    user_id character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    application_id integer,
    terms_accepted boolean,
    CONSTRAINT passport_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT passport_application_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (application_id)
        REFERENCES public.application (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT passport_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public."user" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: if the quesiton is answered, can you mark it as chosen?

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL give me a sec, just came back from having lunch, will implement this right now and let you know.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to insert the same id twice, because `MAX(id)` doesn't get incremented until commit. What you want to do is precisely what the `DEFAULT` does on `passport`

```
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('passport_id_seq'::regclass),
```

Hint: `nextval(seq)`

It'll look like this,

```
INSERT INTO passport (
    id,
    public,
)
SELECT
    nextval('passport_id_seq'::regclass)
    TRUE,
    ...
```

But even better because `id` has a `DEFAULT` just remove it entirely..

```
INSERT INTO passport (
    public,
)
SELECT
    TRUE,
    ...
```